# Save BLOB to doc

Tags: vb6, blob

I'm trying to **save oracle blob to file with extension .doc**,
but getting error: Type mismatch on line oFile.Write "blob content"

Tried to change method, but no luck

```
 BlobToFile
    WriteFromBinary
    WriteFromUnsizedBinary
    WriteFromText 
    WriteFromUnsizedText
```

**My code:**

```
Private Sub cmdOpenWord_Click()

 oraFile.Connect = Name & "/" & code
 oraFile.DatabaseName = OraDatabase.DatabaseName
 oraFile.RecordSource = SQL
 oraFile.Refresh
 If oraFile.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
     Dim oFile As Object
     Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\vba.doc", True, True)
     oFile.Write oraFile.Recordset(1).Value
     oFile.Close
     Set oFile = Nothing
 Else
     No_object.Visible = True
 End If
 End Sub
```

**In watch object is oracleblob type**

```
Watch :: oraFile.Recordset(1).Value :: Variant/Object/IOraBlob :         frmDelete.cmdOpenWord_Click
```

If I try to rewrite I getting another error, looks like visual basic language not suported in visual basic.

```
Sub BlobToFile(ByVal dr As IDataReader, ByVal fieldIndex As Integer, ByVal filename As String)
Const CHUNK_SIZE As Integer = 200
Dim buffer(CHUNK_SIZE - 1) As Byte
Set stream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim index As Long
index = 0
Try
    Do
        ' Get the next chunk, exit if no more bytes.
        Dim length As Integer
        length = CInt(dr.GetBytes(fieldIndex, index, buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE))
        If length = 0 Then Exit Do
        ' Write to file and increment index in field data.
        stream.Write (buffer, 0, length)
        index = index + length
    Loop
Finally
    stream.Close
    End
End Sub
```

Error message: Compile error: User defined type not defined

Comment: oFile.Write takes a string as its argument. Are you passing it something else? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/write-method

Comment: Also, VB6 and VB.Net are very different. You can't use any try... finally in VB6, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, so second code fragment is for vb .net version, how can i rewrite it for vb6 to work?

Comment: __oFile.Write takes a string as its argument. Are you passing it something else?__
I want to write blob context to file(Long string), i Know write method not working, i need like stream writer, but I can't find what to use.

Comment: I don't think you should use a TextStream object if you are not writing text data.

Answer (score 0):

Try **ADODB.Stream**

```
Dim stm As New ADODB.Stream
With stm
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Write oraFile.Recordset(1)
    .SaveToFile "D:\vba.doc", adSaveCreateOverWrite
End With
stm.Close
Set stm = Nothing
```

and try to save in another folder or drive sometimes windows does not allowed save on system drive.